# Why the data in our browser's history is called to be synchronized?

Tags: google-chrome

When I was deleting data from my Chrome's history, it said it is deleting synced data. I wonder in which sense it is synced? Can you explain a little bit about it?

From what I have read:
Data synchronization technologies are designed to synchronize a single set of data between two or more devices, automatically copying changes back and forth.

Comment: Maybe you have set up bookmark/tab/history sync across your devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data in your Chrome browser (such as browsing history, saved passwords etc.) is synchronized with your Google account if you set it up. It meant that it was removing such data which was copied to your Google account.

Answer (score 1):

Google's Chrome Web browser allows you to sync data between Chrome browsers on different computers and devices. So the history from all your devices using chrome and logged in with the same account  will be deleted. You can disable sync from settings -> advanced sync settings.